# Summing through filtered rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hi so I'm currently trying to sum visible values of a filtered row in Excel using VBA aka using SUBTOTAL. My problem is that the number of rows change depending on the filter. I tried to write a code that loops through the rows until it hits a blank cell, and subtotals the visible rows. Any help would be appreciated

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim x As Integer
  NumRows = Range("K15", Range("K15").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  Range("K15").Select
  For x = 1 To NumRows
       H14 = SUBTOTAL(9,"K15" : "NumRows")
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You should check start row (15 here), and cell where sum is written (`Cells(14,8)` in this case, id est, `H8`). Also is usually helpful to define worksheet (`Data` in this case).

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lMySum As Long
    Dim NumRows As Long

    lMySum = 0
    NumRows = Worksheets("Data").Cells(15, 11).End(xlDown).Row
    For x = 15 To NumRows
        If Not (Worksheets("Data").Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden) Then
            lMySum = lMySum + Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 11).Value
        End If
    Next
    Worksheets("Data").Cells(14, 8) = lMySum
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I changed the name "Data" to the worksheet of where I am drawing data from, but I realized that my number doesn't start at K15, but rather it starts 1 below K15 which always changes. Do you happen to have any quick fixes for that?

Comment: `For x = 16 To NumRows` if I correctly undestand you.

Comment: I'm now getting a type mismatch error,  but I've checked the values of the table and they are all integers, so I'm not quite sure where this error is coming from?

Comment: It is useful to insert a breaking point in your code, clicking in the margin of your code (for example in `lMySum = 0`). Run the code, an it will stop at the breaking point. The go step by step with F8. Check the variables hovering over with the mouse (`NumRows` is a posible problem). Code is working for me: I have titles in J14 and K14, and I select the range from there down and apply the filter to that range.